# How to strip HTML tags including escaped image tags without &#39; and &nbsp; stuff?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to strip all the html elements from my content. Example of the content :

```
"<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"/ckeditor_assets/pictures/1/content_twitter-sink.jpg\" style=\"width: 570px; height: 399px;\" /></p>\r\n\r\n<h3 style=\"font-size: 1.38462em; margin: 1em 0px 0px; font-weight: 600; line-height: 1.2; font-family: freight-sans-pro, sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-rendering: optimizelegibility; color: rgb(46, 46, 46);\">Soraya Calavassy, communications manager at the Award in Australia,&nbsp;shares her organisation&#39;s experience&nbsp;piloting our new global visual identity.</h3>\r\n\r\n<p style=\"margin: 0.5em 0px 0px; text-rendering: optimizelegibility; font-size: 1.30769em; line-height: 1.3; color: rgb(78, 78, 78); font-family: freight-sans-pro, sans-serif;\">&quot;While Australia has a very strong brand locally, there are some great benefits for incorporating"
```

When displaying the post i use raw which does give me the output I need. But I need to generate an excerpt. For that, I need to strip all the HTML tags and even remove the images. But when I use **sanitize**  it won't remove the images. If I use **strip_tags** , it will remove the images but it will add `&#39;` for apostrophe, `&nbsp;` for space, etc. So, how to get a clean  excerpt without images and without `&nbsp;` stuff?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try `strip_tags(text).html_safe`

Comment: It worked :) Before posting the question also I tried it. But tried in the console. It (html_safe) seems to be working only on the browser. Not in the console :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me in Rails 4.1 Any ideas?

Comment: try `raw strip_tags(text)`

Comment: In Rails 4.0.2 doesn't remove &nbsp; ..etc

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't work with rails 4.1

Only way by combing strip_tags with the gsub function (link below)

[Ruby gsub multiple characters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650681/ruby-gsub-multiple-characters-in-string)

So in helper, I'd do:

```
def format_text(string)
    strip_tags(string).gsub("&nbsp;", "").gsub("&#39;", "'")
end
```

Comment: Is it really the only solution??? It should be a helper to remove html characters like &nbsp;

Answer (score 1):

I meet problem with such code

```
strip_tags("<p>a</p>\r\n") # => a&#13;
```

I use

```
sanitize("<p>a</p>", tags: [ ]) # => a\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

`raw(strip_tags(text).html_safe)` is actually what you want

Comment: In Rails 4.0.2 doesn't remove &nbsp; ..etc