# Ruby gsub multiple characters in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2, I have the following:

```
"every good boy does fine".gsub("every", "all").gsub("boy", "girl").gsub("fine", "well")
# => "all good girl does well"
```

Is there a better way to write this? Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) and [`Hash#fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) will be the good choice for this.

```
a = "every good boy does fine"
h = {"every" => "all","boy" => "girl", "fine" =>"well" }
a.gsub(/\w+/) { |m| h.fetch(m,m)}
# => "all good girl does well"
```

or,

```
a = "every good boy does fine"
h = {"every" => "all","boy" => "girl", "fine" =>"well" }
Regexp.new("^#{h.keys.join('|')}$") # => /^every|boy|fine$/
a.gsub(Regexp.new("^#{h.keys.join('|')}$"),h)
# => "all good girl does well"
```

Comment: Clever use of `Regexp.union` however `'no finer boy'.gsub(Regexp.union(*h.keys),h)` -> `"no wellr girl"`

Comment: I find my original approach, though not the best, is more readable. Nevertheless, thanks for teaching. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
replacements = [ ["every", "all"], ["boy", "girl"],["fine", "well"]
replacements.each {|replacement| str.gsub!(replacement[0], replacement[1])}
```

I don't know if its better, but much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
subs = { "every" => "all", "boy" => "girl", "fine" => "well" }
"every good boy does fine".gsub(/\w+/) { |m| subs[m] || m }
# => 'all good girl does well'
```

Comment: `subs[m] || m` far better than `h.has_key?(m) ? h[m] : m` .. I forgot that, but you reminds me.. :)

Comment: `subs.default_proc = ->(h, k) { k }` is another option, then you could just say `{ |m| subs[m] }` and hide the conditional behind the `default_proc`.

Comment: @muistooshort More better is `a.gsub(/\w+/) { |m| h.fetch(m,m)}` :) Look at my edit.

Answer (score 1):

just do this:

```
"every good boy does fine".gsub(/\w+/, 'every' => 'all', 'boy' => 'girl', 'fine' => 'well')
```

a lot easier to read :)
some of the answers here to this simple question really make me wonder...lol

here's the reference:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html

gg

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to avoid method chaining:

```
[9] pry(main)> "every good boy does fine".gsub("every", "all").gsub("boy", "girl").gsub("fine", "well")
=> "all good girl does well"
[10] pry(main)> "every good boy does fine".gsub(/(every)|(boy)|(fine)/) do |word|
[10] pry(main)*   case word
[10] pry(main)*   when "every"
[10] pry(main)*     "all"
[10] pry(main)*   when "boy"
[10] pry(main)*     "girl"
[10] pry(main)*   when "fine"
[10] pry(main)*     "well"
[10] pry(main)*   end
[10] pry(main)* end
=> "all good girl does well"
```

Alternatively:

```
[11] pry(main)> REPLACEMENT = { "every" => "all", "boy" => "girl", "fine" => "well"}
=> {"every"=>"all", "boy"=>"girl", "fine"=>"well"}
[12] pry(main)> "every good boy does fine".gsub(/(every)|(boy)|(fine)/) { |word| REPLACEMENT[word] }
=> "all good girl does well"
```