# Before save model gsub not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to have it so that when my form is submitted, I do some gsub validation on the model level before it is saved to the database.

Here's my model code:

```
class Blast < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :inliner

    def inliner
        self.body.gsub!('class=\"wysiwyg-color-grey\"' => 'style="color: #A9A9A9;"',
                                     'class=\"wysiwyg-color-blue\"' => 'style="color: #333399;"',
                                     'class=\"wysiwyg-color-purple\"' => 'style="color: #663399;"',
                                     'class=\"wysiwyg-color-red\"' => 'style="color: #CC3333;"',
                                     'class=\"wysiwyg-color-orange\"' => 'style="color: #FF6633;"',
                                     'class=\"wysiwyg-color-yellow\"' => 'style="color: #FFCC33;"',
                                     'class=\"wysiwyg-color-green\"' => 'style="color: #009933;"')
    end

end
```

Here's my controller code:

```
  def emailblastcreate
    email = Blast.create(blast_params)
    user = current_user
    PanelMailer.blast(user, email).deliver
  end
```

Can't seem to wrap my head around it, any insight would be great.

Comment: You don't need to escape double quotes if your string is single-quoted. That's the problem, I think

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Even if I remove the \ it doesn't work - Also, when being saved the console is showing the double quotes with escapes so I presumed I needed to put them in as well

Comment: Not sure that the bang (!) version of gsub accepts a hash? 
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub-21

Comment: @BenPolinsky Tried without, still no luck :(

Comment: Indeed - I've never used a hash with gsub.  But the docs say you need to provide a pattern as the first parameter, then the hash...

Check it out: http://batsov.com/articles/2013/10/03/using-rubys-gsub-with-a-hash/

Comment: @BenPolinsky Ah, I have no idea how I'd implement a key for this scenario, hmm

Comment: @JohnLong split your one multi-gsub (which doesn't work) into several single-purpose ones (which will likely work).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I added a gsub for a simple word switch just to narrow down what wasn't working, turns out the gsub isn't working at all. This is extremely weird :(

Comment: Must be you're using it the wrong way. It most certainly works.

Comment: Try this one: `self.body.gsub!('class="wysiwyg-color-grey"',  'style="color: #A9A9A9;"')` (note: no hash)

Comment: Just tried: self.body.gsub!('purple', 'test') with no luck

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I don't think you have used `gsub` correctly. Here is one way to re-write your method.

```
before_save :inliner

def inliner

  regex_hash = {
    Regexp.new(%Q(class="wysiwyg-color-grey"))   => 'style="color: #A9A9A9;"',
    Regexp.new(%Q(class="wysiwyg-color-blue"))   => 'style="color: #333399;"',
    Regexp.new(%Q(class="wysiwyg-color-purple")) => 'style="color: #663399;"',
    Regexp.new(%Q(class="wysiwyg-color-red"))    => 'style="color: #CC3333;"',
    Regexp.new(%Q(class="wysiwyg-color-orange")) => 'style="color: #FF6633;"',
    Regexp.new(%Q(class="wysiwyg-color-yellow")) => 'style="color: #FFCC33;"',
    Regexp.new(%Q(class="wysiwyg-color-green"))  => 'style="color: #009933;"'
  }

  regex_hash.each do |regex_exp, val|
    self.body.gsub!(regex_exp, val)
  end

end
```

You can also refer to following to improve the syntax further:

[Ruby gsub multiple characters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650681/ruby-gsub-multiple-characters-in-string)

[Ruby multiple string replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132492/ruby-multiple-string-replacement)

Comment: Also not good. `before_create` and `before_save` are two very different callbacks. The problem is in his code, not the activemodel callback (which works)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the final version, and removed older ones. Check now. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do `%r[class="wysiwyg-color-grey"]` instead of `Regexp.new(%Q(class="wysiwyg-color-grey"))`

Comment: Also it'd be great to add some description as to why you think this will work (instead of plain "try following")